# Archiving text messages (sms)

Tags: windows-mobile, sms, rapi

I want to archive the text messages on my WM phone to my PC, preferably as XML. Can I access them from a PC application, e.g. through RAPI? I have no experience in WM development, just PC, and then mainly Delphi.

Please no links to commercial application unless you think that's the only possible way.

**Edit**
No-one? You guys disappoint me :-). Or is that :-(?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use PIM Backup to export my SMS messages. http://www.dotfred.net/

It can export the messages in binary or text (csv, no xml sorry)

It generates a .pib file that you can rename to .zip and then extract to find the exported text files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this app can help you: http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/Enhancements/AllExport-9131.shtml

Answer (score 0):

To get access to SMS messages you use Windows Mobile [Messaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446118.aspx) services. Specifically you need to use the [MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415647.aspx) to get access to all SMS's.  This assumes that the device is using the Windows Mobile SMS Messaging, some don't.  On the devices that don't you have to use Manufactor API's to access the SMS messages.

You can't access MAPI directly from RAPI, but you could use RAPI to push down and run your own application which would communicate back to the PC.  There are a number of ways of doing this.